# iPhone KVO crash (SIGSEV)

Tags: ios, iphone, crash, key-value-observing

I am loading details of an object with NSURLRequest. This object has a property 'isLoading'.
In the ViewController to show the object details, the object has an Observer for 'isLoading'.

This observer will be registered in in 'loadFromResultList' (called in 'viewWillAppear') and it will be unregistered in 'observeValueForKeyPath' or in 'viewWillDisappear' (if necessary).

Sometimes the app crashes with 'no reason' (Exception type SIGSEGV).
So it means the observer message is sent to a deallocated object.

I tried using enabled NSZombies. But this crash is only occurring sometimes. So i can't really track it.

Here is the Code:

```
// ViewController
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    if (self.advertisement == nil) 
    {
        [self loadAdFromResultList];
    }
}

- (void)loadAdFromResultList {
    self.advertisement = [appDelegate.currentSearch.result objectAtIndex:self.currentAdIndex];

    if ([self.advertisement isKindOfClass:[NSError class]]) {
    } else {
        [self.advertisement addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"isLoading" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:NULL];
         @try {
             [self.advertisement load];
         } @catch […]
     }
}

// Advertisment Object class
- (void)load {
        self.isLoading = true;
        [api beginGetAdvertisement:guid target:self selector:@selector(beginGetAdvertisementCallback:) userState:self];
}

// ViewController
- (void)beginGetAdvertisementCallback:(FEURLAsyncResult*)result {
    […]
    [api endGetAdvertisement:result];

    self.isLoading = false;
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"isLoading"]) {
        @try {
            // Remove observer
            [self.advertisement removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"isLoading"];
        }
        @catch (NSException *exception) {
            NSLog(@"[x] %s: %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, exception);
        }
    }
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    @try {
        [self.advertisement removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"isLoading"];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"err: %@", exception);
    }
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

And here is the Stacktrace:

```
    Thread 0 Crashed:
1    libobjc.A.dylib     _objc_msgSend + 6
2    Foundation  NSKeyValuePushPendingNotificationPerThread + 215
3    Foundation  NSKeyValueWillChange + 475
4    Foundation  -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObserverNotification) willChangeValueForKey:] + 181
5    Foundation  _NSSetCharValueAndNotify + 77
6    Fewo    -[FEAdvertisement load] + 381
7    Fewo    -[FEExposeViewController loadAdFromResultList] (FEExposeViewController.m:1145)
8    Fewo    -[FEExposeViewController viewWillAppear:] (FEExposeViewController.m:122)
9    UIKit   -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 347
…
14   Fewo    -[FEResultListViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] (FEResultListViewController.m:358)
15   UIKit   -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 1079
…
26   Fewo    main (main.m:17)
```

Any ideas what can cause this crash r welcome.

Thx to all

Comment: You don't have a matching `@catch` inside `loadAdFromResultList`.

Comment: I do have this in the code. Just forgot to write in #1. I edited it.

Comment: Do you have any background threads (e.g. dispatch_async) running which use this object? A background dealloc would cause this problem